# Struggling to get datepicker for dynamically created textboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

I have generated textbox dynamically and trying to get date picker for each textboxes separately.

The problem is if i select a text box and pick date it will apply for all textboxes. I don't know how to pass the value to get the result. Please forgive If my English (or) the way I expressed is wrong. I will be thankful for your help.

My Script to call calendar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load( function() {

    $('#mycalendar3').monthly({
        mode: 'picker1',
        target: '#mytarget1',
        setWidth: '370px',
        startHidden: true,
        showTrigger: '#mytarget1',
        stylePast: true,
        disablePast: true,
                    xmlUrl: 'events.xml'
    });


                $('#mycalendar2').monthly({
        mode: 'picker1',
        target: '.value1',
        setWidth: '370px',
        startHidden: true,
        showTrigger: '.value1',
        stylePast: true,
        disablePast: true,
                    xmlUrl: 'events.xml'
    });



switch(window.location.protocol) {
case 'http:':
case 'https:':
// running on a server, should be good.
break;
case 'file:':
alert('Just a heads-up, events will not work when run locally.');
}

});
```

HTML code:

```
 <div style="display:inline-block; width:150px;">
                  <input type="text"  class="value1" id="mytarget" >
        <div class="monthly" id="mycalendar2"></div>
    </div>


              <div style="display:inline-block; width:150px;">
        <input type="text" id="mytarget1">
        <div class="monthly" id="mycalendar3"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: don't see any issue with above code. Is there any other code which is missing in this post? How the textboxes are getting generated dynamically? can you please show that code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ssoundar619/eav8hLwm/1/

Comment: Please refer this link Vijay. I have pasted my entire code there.

Comment: If you're using `$(window).load(` to set the events, but the textboxes are generated "dynamically" - there's a good chance that they're generated *after* you've attempted to **convert** them (code not in the question).    Add `alert($('#mycalendar3').length)` just before the `.monthly` call to see if they exist yet.

Comment: I have refered that post Sir. It is not working in my scenerio. @freedomn-m

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include setting the month control

Comment: The alert shows 1 Sir. What can i do to change the function to work for dynamic elements sir?

Comment: I have used $(window).load() like u said but i tried to change that and still the function is not working properly sir @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery on event, I have created demo fiddle here,

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  $("button").on('click', function() {
    $('.output').append('<input type="text" name="gentext" id="gent" />');
    $("#gent").datepicker();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Normal input datepicker</h3>
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
<button>generate</button>
<h3>Generated input datepicker</h3>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Please apply the same event on your code, it will work on generated inputs.